# Extract Data of a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have got a simple requirement of extracting data out of the data stored by the WordPress plugin into a third-party system.

I am relatively new to the WordPress platform. Wondering what are some of the right ways of extracting data belonging to a particular plugin. Does WordPress expose any API to extract plugin data? Or would I need to extract data using an intermediary program that connects to the WordPress database and reads the data from selected tables of this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you want to read data from a plugin using API you can write your own API endpoint for this reason.
You have to read the plugin code and find the name of db table or functions that insert or select the data and create a simple plugin with copy of that function and send data using your API.
.

```
<?php

function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
  // get data and return to your API using plugin code or db table
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/getdata', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
  ) );
} );
```

Then you can access to your API from [www.example.com/wp-json/myplugin/v1/getdata](http://www.example.com/wp-json/myplugin/v1/getdata) .

read more in this links:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: ¿Can you elaborate?

Comment: Have you access to the plugin code?